# SingleResult and UnitTesting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method in my `BaseApiController` class:

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage GetById(int id)
{
   var entity = repository.GetById(id);

   if (entity == null)
   {                
     var message = string.Format("No {0} with ID = {1}", GenericTypeName, id);
     return ErrorMsg(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
   }

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, SingleResult.Create(repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id)));
}
```

I'm using `SingleResult` for OData request (because `$expand` for single entity not works if I not create SingleResult). 

But now I have problem with UnitTests of this method on concrete controller (e.g. AddressApiController). I always get `NULL` in result:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_By_Id()
{
    //Arrange
    var moq = CreateMockRepository();
    var controller = new AddressApiController(moq);
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    controller.Request.SetConfiguration(new HttpConfiguration())
    // Action
    HttpResponseMessage response = controller.GetById(1);
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;

    // Accert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I checked and debug `GetById()` and find out that `repository.Table.Where(t => t.ID == id))` return proper value, but after `SingleResult.Create` I'm getting `NULL`.

How can I solve this problem? How can I read content from SingleResult or using something else?

Comment: Do you test base controller? Please show more full example of your code.

Comment: No, I'm testing concrete controller. I've updated question.

Comment: Everything works fine before I added `SingleResult.Create`

Comment: shouldn't it be `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<**SingleResult** >().Result' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created extensions:

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> ContentToQueryable<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response) where T : BaseEntity
        {
            var objContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;
            return objContent?.Value as IQueryable<T>;
        }

        public static T ContentToEntity<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response) where T : BaseEntity
        {
            var objContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;
            return objContent?.Value as T;
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
 var result = response.ContentToEntity<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to mock up an api but from the docs here:

Here are some rules for the method signatures: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions

Try change `id` to `key` and attribute, then you probably won't need to use `SingleResult`.

- If the path contains a key, the action should have a parameter named key.
- If the path contains a key into a navigation property, the action should have a parameter named relatedKey.
- Decorate key and relatedKey parameters with the [FromODataUri] parameter.
- POST and PUT requests take a parameter of the entity type.
- PATCH requests take a parameter of type Delta, where T is the entity type.

I would be interested to see if that changes the test outcome.

Comment: I do not use ODataController and  routing like /odata/Products(1)/Suppliers(1). And I saw this article